# expo no muestra las imagenes

Tags: react-native, expo

estoy teniendo un problema al querer visualizar una imagen en una app echa con react-native que utiliza expo, la aplicación fue generada con el comando `expo init` aqui es donde llamo a la imagen

```
<View style={{width, height: 'auto'}}>
  <Image
    source={require("./../assets/logo.png")}
    width={100}
    height={100}
  />
</View>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

arriba del campo usuario tendria que ir el logo de la app, lo que esta pasando es que el logo no se muestra y no entiendo por que, yo pienso que el problema puede ser al cargar las imagenes en el `appLoading` de expo, aqui les dejo mi archivo que maneja ese modulo

```
import React from 'react';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useUsuario } from '../context';

export default class App extends React.Component<any,any> {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
    usuario: null
  };

  userData = useUsuario()

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._cacheResourcesAsync}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
          onError={console.warn}
        />
      ); }
      const { usuario } = this.userData
    return (
      <>
        {usuario ?
          this.props.navigation.navigate("App")
        :
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth")
        }
      </>
    );
  }

  async _cacheResourcesAsync(): Promise<any> {
    try {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
    const images = [require('./../assets/logo.png')];
    const cacheImages = images.map(image => {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }); 
    return Promise.all(cacheImages);
  }
}
```

cualquier comentario u oponiendo serán bien recibidas, muchísimas gracias por su tiempo